# How do GHC.Generics representations work?

Tags: haskell, generics, ghc

I am really confused by the *'Generic representation type'* in GHC.Generics. I don't understand how this datatype works. For example, Meta-information, `M1`:

```
newtype M1 i c f p
M1
  unM1 :: f p
```

Why edoes the type `M1` have four type variables: i, c, f and p. By that I mean, why *4*. Does it have some special meaning?

Also, any books or papers good for learning about GHC Generics for beginners would be appreciated.

Comment: `M1` stores meta-information. `i` indicates if it is storing a record selector, constructor, or datatype. `c` is a tag generated for each datatype - it allows you to access the name of the original datatype, record selector, or constructor as a string, as well as other things. `f` is the "branches" of the datatype, and `p` the "leaves". All of this is in the docs for [GHC.Generics](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/GHC-Generics.html).

Answer (score 0):

There are not a lot of resources out there for GHC.Generics. Your best bet is the documentation in hackage, blog posts and reading source code.

Here is a simplified reference list of type synonyms I keep in order to remember what all the types from GHC.Generics mean.

```
type TypeName = D1 ('MetaSelector name moduleName packageName isNewType) rest
-- Company from data Company = MkCompany { name :: String, address :: String }

type Constructor = C1 ('MetaCons constructor prefixOrInfix isRecord) rest
-- MkCompany from data Company = MkCompany { name :: String, address :: String }

type NamedSelector = S1 ('MetaSel ('Just selector) unpackednesss sourceStrictness decidedStrictness)
-- age from data Person = Person { age :: Int }

type UnnamedSelector = S1 ('MetaSel Nothing unpackednesss sourceStrictness decidedStrictness)
-- Int from data Wrapper = Wrapper Int

type ConcatSelectors = (:*:)

type ConcatConstructors = (:+:)

type TypeParameter a = Rec0 a
-- a from the right side of data Wrapper a = Wrapper {getA :: a}

type ConstructorEmptyValuePlaceholder = U1
-- data Empty = MkEmpty, MkEmpty is a Constructor but takes no values
-- ConstructorEmptyValuePlaceholder fills the type requirement of Constructor
```

Comment: You have two things called `EmptySelector`. I don't understand the syntax of this list. Like ... what is `Selector typ` supposed to mean?

Comment: @dfeuer I cleaned it up a bit and fixed the naming. The things on the left are supposed to be type synonyms. It is only a reference to help make sense of the documentation in GHC.Generics. It isn't intended to be used in real code.

Comment: `U1` doesn't have any selectors (it has no fields, so it can't). I'm not sure what you mean there.

Comment: @dfeuer Thanks for the feedback

Comment: For `U1` I meant to express that for a particular Constructor it has no selectors. I am still trying to think of a better name for it.